Selecting studies and papers for a literature review
We aim to conduct a literature review that concentrates on specific regions, encompassing 21 countries. Our objective is to include all studies conducted within each country, recognizing that a single country may have a hundred or more publications on the subject. Should we strive to incorporate all studies from each country? Furthermore, could the selection of certain papers over others introduce bias into our review? I seek to comprehend the criteria employed in selecting articles for the review. Specifically, I am interested in the number of articles considered and the basis upon which certain articles are included in the review while others are excluded

Welcome to Academia SE! This is a good question, but unfortunately, in my opinion, not a good question for this site. This site is for general questions about academic life but it explicitly excludes questions about the content of research projects; see https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. Such questions are too specific for this site. In other words, your question's answer is too specific to your research project and would not be generally helpful to academics with other research questions.

I think there's A LOT to unpack here, the first and most important aspect being that you don't clarify what exactly you want to study.
If you want to study relationships between authors/institutions/countries, then a bibliometric analysis is what you want. Specific packages exist for this (such as Bibliometrix for R or websites like connected-papers), mainly for automation of article meta info collection, categorisation and graphs generation. Such programs mean that there's not a lot of work for researchers, but you have to establish good search queries for each database you're accessing.
If you want to do a narrative review, then you just have to read a lot about the subject you're interested in. A narrative review is more or less a story putting together the results of other papers, without creating new knowledge directly. It's subjective, and (as far as I know) not many people would hold narrative reviews to a high standard. As such, those are seldom judged for biases, because it's assumed that the authors have picked their preferred sources anyways.
Lastly, what I think is probably what you want, is a systematic review. The systematic review is based on a highly specific research question, and all articles on that subject are collected and analyzed. PRISMA is a tool/guideline that explains the steps of a systematic review better. Such a research has a well-established protocol even before starting the review, which is prospectively put up on the web in a database such as PROSPERO (CRD from University of York). Once you establish a protocol, you have to adhere to it, even if some countries are under-represented in your sample (unless you explicitly mentioned ways to select articles based on country - see later).

Should we strive to incorporate all studies from each country?

Yes, otherwise you would have to establish a mechanism to choose specific articles from each country when there's too many, and that would introduce a bias.

Furthermore, could the selection of certain papers over others
introduce bias into our review?

Yes, depending on how you're choosing which articles to prioritize.

I seek to comprehend the criteria employed in selecting articles for the review. Specifically, I am interested in the number of articles considered and the basis upon which certain articles are included in the review while others are excluded

Unless you would provide more detail on what exactly you want to study, it's impossible for us to give you a definitive answer. Some criteria can be (examples from biomedicine):

Type of research: observational, interventional/experimental (testing new medicine)
Data collection timeline of original studies: are only prospective studies accepted (being more rigorous) or do we include retrospective studies also (those having their own biases)
Does the article contain the data I'm interested in? If, for example, I'm studying smoking behavior among diabetes patients, I won't include clinical trials for diabetes that don't contain any data on smoking.
Location, time, demographics if relevant: if I'm studying vitamin D levels in a population, I might choose to limit the included articles based on region (I'm interested in countries at specific latitudes, I won't combine data from Greenland with data from Ecuador). I might choose to study only articles based on data collected during the summer (when people are outside). I might even choose to include/exclude articles based on the skin color of the subjects (because of differences in vitamin D synthesis in light/dark skin color).

Lastly, as @Buffy has mentioned, before embarking on making a systematic review, you can do a scoping review, where you try different research questions, search queries, article selection criteria, in order to see what is possible or not.

If your goal is to include all studies, as you say, then you pretty much need to include all studies.
But, if you have a less comprehensive goal then you could restrict to recent studies or to "frequently cited" studies. You would need to include at least one study from each country, perhaps, though that might not fit your exclusion criteria. You might look at a citation graph among those you find to get an idea of the most important studies.
Before you start including or excluding papers, however, you first need to determine whether you are, in any sense, comparing countries or comparing studies independent of country. That isn't clear from your post, but needs to be clear in your mind. And comparing might not be what you are after, I realize.
First get a sense of the scope involved. Tens of thousands of articles isn't a reasonable task to attempt.
